# unordered list in drupal views

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have about nine fields on a page view (that is i have used views to create a page) In that page, i would like to output about four of those fields as an unordered list. Not all 9 fields, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should write a specific view template for doing this.

http://drupal.org/node/352970

You can also : exclude from display the first 3 fields, and check *Rewrite the output of this field* on the fourth field to display the four fields like you want (you will need token module). But this will cause w3c validation error since *ul* is not allowed inside *span*.